# calculated field Pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

*I would like to get the percentage based on Total value by **Product

```
Category**,**Product**,**Product type**,**Supplier**.

**Product Category  Product     Order no    Qty   Value net value   Product type    Supplier**
HAYYAK_EXPRESS      E_HAYYAK_10 1661993     1     10    9.2           EXPRESS       OT
FRIENDI_EXPRESS     E_FRIENDI_1 1661994     1     1     0.93          EXPRESS       FRIE
HAYYAK_PHYSICAL     E_HAYYAK_1  1661995    20     20    18.7          EXPRESS       OT
```

Comment: format the style of your question, make cleaner and add an image of your data sheet, and if possible expected results.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the pivot table, drag the "Value" field to the "Values" box in the pivot table Field List twice. Drag the "Product" field to the "Row Labels" box.

Click the drop-down arrow on the second one (Probably named "Sum of Value2"), then click "Value Field Settings."

Click the "Show Values As" tab, then in the drop-down box select "% of Grand Total," then hit OK.

The end result should look like this:

[image]